# Not an array and not a string, what type of data is?

Tags: javascript, vector, initialization, counter, items

I found a script in js but I don't understand what type of data is the variable "n".
The script is:

```
var buttons= document.getElementByTagName("button");

var n= buttons.length, counters=[];

//initialize the vector of counters

counters.length= n;

counters.______ (0);
```

There is a vector and an integer inside the variable n?

Another question, the exercise is to complete, can I write counters.items(0) in the last row or I can use "items()" just with two numbers inside the brackets?

Thanks

Comment: `var n= buttons.length` and `.length` contains a number, so n is a number

Comment: `getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't understand which is second ".length" you wrote. Is "counter=[ ]" an empty array, rigth? How is possible I have a number that contains another number and an array? I imagine the variable n like: var n= 6, [2,5,1,9]; where 6 is the buttons length and 2,5,1,9 items of the array "counters"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all buttons on the page with a counter, the counter becomes useles because we will transform the collection to an array, and you can count from there, this is a example to understand better, try this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); // here the var buttons become a collection of html elements
var numberOfElements = buttons.length; // here you get the size of the collection
var collectionOfElements = [].slice.call(buttons); //since getElementsByTagName will return a collection of html elements you need to transform them to array

console.log("Number of elements: " + numberOfElements);
console.log(collectionOfElements); // printing the array
```

Comment: Thanks but it's an excercise to completion so I can't change the script :)

Comment: @Ale17 please explain then, you need counters being populated with integers ? i dont understand

Comment: I don't know me too, this is a script my teacher wrote in an old test and I have to complete it. In comment line he tells "counters" is a vector

Comment: @Ale17 vectors in js are just arrays, your example is written with errors, you cannot complete something that cannot run as it is

Comment: @Ale17 for example var n= buttons.length, counters=[]; i assume you want n to become an object ? but this will never work, in order to make it an object you need to write var n = {length:buttons.length, counters:[]}; and so on

Comment: Thanks man, I'm really bad in programming and I have no idea of what this teacher want, all the script is a mess. Thanks again